# Error CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0 with a (picker) window rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I get this error `("CGImageCreate: invalid image size: 0 x 0")` with iOS 6 in an universal project, only for new iPad simulator (not for the old one or the iPhone) if I load a window with a `UIPickerViewController` over a `splitViewController` and only in portrait (not in landscape).

when I rotate the iPad I get the error.

I don't think to have images that could generate the error... Why?

The code I use to load picker:

```
- (void) pickerViewControllerDidFinish:(PickerViewController *)controller {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.path = controller.path;             
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        FeedRootViewController *controllerF = [[FeedRootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FeedRootViewController" bundle:nil];
        controllerF.path = self.path;
        controllerF.detailViewController = self.detailViewController;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController: controllerF animated:YES];
        [controllerF release];  
        NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"feeds" ofType:@"html"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [detailViewController.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
        [detailViewController.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
        [path release];
    }
}
```

However I don't know if the problem is from this code or not...

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, and my app is iPhone only, using iOS 6. I seem to see it during Game Center authentication, or when I navigate to / from my Game Center view. It see it sporadically and have no idea why.

Comment: Have you implemented the new orientation methods introduced in iOS 6? Namely **supportedInterfaceOrientations** and **shouldAutorotate**?

Comment: have you tried on the device? Never use the simulator for serious development cause it is not trustable.

Answer (score 1):

Last line of your code `[path release];` looks quite suspicious. If **path** is a local variable insure it isn't released in the **dealloc** method. If it released **path** property of **FeedRootViewController** can become undefined and you will get an error. Also do not mix properties with local variables, it can cause errors and makes your code unreadable.